# jQuery.get executa depois de todo resto da função

Tags: jquery, get

Executando esse código a sequencia de alerts que eu tenho é `begin, outside, final e inside`, como resolver isso ??

```
        addLine(){
            alert('begin')
            jQuery.get('database/addClube/'+this.clube);

            jQuery.get('database/getClubes', function(data){
                this.list = data;
                console.log(this.list);
                alert('inside')
            });

            console.log(this.list);
            alert('outside')
            for(item in this.list){
                //alert(item);
            }

            this.clube = '';
            alert('final')
        },
```

Comment: Aprenda a criar Promises, é esse o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar assim, pois o get pode demorar um pouco para trazer os dados dependendo do volume:

```
         addLine(){
            alert('begin')
            jQuery.get('database/addClube/'+this.clube);

            jQuery.get('database/getClubes', function(data){
                this.list = data;
                console.log(this.list);
                alert('inside');

                for(item in this.list){
                    //alert(item);
                }
            });

            this.clube = '';
            alert('final')
        },
```

Comment: Mas mesmo o GET demorando, ele continua não colocando na `list`, mesmo depois de minutos na pagina.

Answer (score 0):

O método jQuery.get() é, por padrão, assíncrono, isto é, cria uma nova thread para baixar a página em questão e continua o javascript. A nova thread depois responde ao download efetuado chamando a sua função ali.

Você pode usar o método [`jQuery.get(settings)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings), passando todos os parâmetros através de um objeto e um deles sendo o parâmetro `async`. Passando `false` para ele, a requisição não é feita em outra thread e com isso espera o retorno para continuar o seu script, porém pode prejudicar a experiência do usuário ao usar a página:

```
        jQuery.get({
            async: false;
            url: 'database/getClubes',
            success: function(data) {
                this.list = data;
                console.log(this.list);
                alert('inside');

                for(item in this.list){
                    //alert(item);
                }
            },
        });
```

Ou Poderia tentar desta forma:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'database/getClubes',
        success: function(data) {

            this.list = data;
                console.log(this.list);
                alert('inside');

                for(item in this.list){
                    //alert(item);
                }

        },
        error: function(data) {

            // handle the response
            // show the UI again

        }
    });
```

Faça o mesmo para o primeiro `get()` inclusive, entretanto recomendo usar o [`post(settings)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) para as modificações, como adicionar ou atualizar a base.

Comment: Quando tento usar desta forma diz que esse método `async` está obsoleto.

Comment: @LucasCarezia adicionei mais um trecho a resposta e verifique se te ajuda

Comment: Lucas, na verdade é que não é recomendado, pois fazer a thread principal parar para esperar o download não é bom para a experiência do usuário na página, o método que o Otto adicionou é o mais recomendado.